# Stick UIView to top of screen

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiscrollview

I try to stick an UIView to the top of the screen.

I use following code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

var navigationBarOriginalOffset : CGFloat?

@IBOutlet weak var navigationBar: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    scrollView.delegate = self
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    navigationBarOriginalOffset = navigationBar.frame.origin.y
}

func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    navigationBar.frame.origin.y = max(navigationBarOriginalOffset!, scrollView.contentOffset.y)
    print("did scroll")
}
}
```

but the view doesn't stick, it scrolls together with the scrollview.

How can I make it stick?

Comment: I think in the storyboard you have added the UView as a subview to the Scrollview. Put it outside the Scrollview

Comment: tried this - no effect :(

Answer (score 2):

You can add constraints of the view you want to stick to the main view or to the top layout Guide. This would do the trick

Comment: Never thought about this simple solution and it works XD

Comment: If this doesn't work, make sure that you set all other views's height constraint.